# don't understand type equivalence

Tags: haskell, types

A Haskell tutorial ( https://www.fpcomplete.com/haskell/tutorial/monad-transformers/ ) says that, if we assume the following definition

```
newtype State s a = State (s -> (s, a))
```

then the following definition

```
newtype StateEither s e a = StateEither (State s (Either e a))
```

is a re-write of

```
newtype StateEither s e a = StateEither (s -> (s, Either e a))
```

What steps of substitution make this possible?

Comment: No, the definition is not a rewrite, your `newtype` produces a new type, it is not an alias.

Comment: The tutorial also does not say that, it says that the two are very similar, and that *you* can rewrite the first in the second as in these are similar, but a type checker does *not* consider these two the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two are not a rewrite of each other: a type checker will not deduce that the two are the same. The two are however very similar.

Indeed, the `State` type is defined as:

```
newtype State s a = State (s -> (s, a))
```

This means that for a `State s a`, it *wraps* an `s -> (a, s)` function into a `State` data constructor. If we thus remove the `State` data constructor, we can see this as a function with type `s -> (a, s)`, so:

```
type State s a = s -> (s, a)
```

In that case the type `State s (Either e a)` thus has type:

```
s -> (s, Either e a)
```

and so:

```
newtype StateEither s e a = StateEither (State s (Either e a))
```

would be equivalent to:

```
newtype StateEither s e a = StateEither (s -> (s, Either e a))
```

Here a `newtype` is however used. This is useful to define a different instance for typeclasses, since an function is an instance of `Monad` as well, but we want to define a different `instance` for the `Monad` for a `State`.

Comment: Ah, I am still looking at it - but I think you may have explained what I was confused about: the presence of that extra `State` on the right-hand side of the final re-write. You are saying that that occurrence of `State` is the `newtype` data constructor, which is removed on compilation to reveal the type. This is my assumption.

Comment: @BenWeaver: the data constructor will be removed after compilation yes, but the type system will use `State` to find out what `instance` of `Monad` (or other typeclasses) to use for polymorphic functions.

Comment: Ok, yes, I can see how `State` would be necessary. I had been wondering in the back of my mind how the State monad would be sought. After all, `s -> (s, Either e a)` by itself, I had worred, could be any old function.

Answer (score 2):

With `Data.Type.Coercion` it can be proven by the compiler that they are equal. A value of such a type contains a witness that the two types are Coercible:

```hs
witness :: Coercion (State s (Either e a))
                    (s -> (Either e a, s))
witness = Coercion
```

A more productive way of witnessing this is getting instances from it.

If you can derive instances for `StateEither s e` via `Compose (State s) (Either e)` that's proof they are representationally equal.

```hs
type    StateEither :: Type -> Type -> Type -> Type
newtype StateEither s e a = StateEither (s -> (Either e a, s))
  deriving (Functor, Applicative)
  via Compose (State s) (Either e)
```

When fully applied, `StateEither s e a` is not only isomorphic to `State s (Either e a)` but they are represented identically in memory and coercible at zero cost.

```
   StateEither s e a
~R Compose (State s) (Either e) a
~R State s (Either e a)
~R s -> (a, Either e a)
```